# iOS - awakeFromNib of UITableViewCell gets called when an NSNotification is received

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

NSNotification observers are added when `awakeFromNib` is called in my `UITableViewCell`. Then, I am removing the observers when `removeFromSuperView` is called.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self setNotificationObserver];

    _vHolder.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    _vHolder.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _vHolder.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    _vHolder.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    _vHolder.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
}

- (void)removeFromSuperview
{
    [super removeFromSuperview];

    [self removeNotificationObserver];
}

- (void)setNotificationObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveESSMQTTMessageNotification:) name:NOTIF_ESSMQTT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveDeviceStatesMessageNotification:) name:NOTIF_DEVICE_STATES_RECEIVED object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveDeviceOnOffStateNotification:) name:NOTIF_DEVICE_ON_OFF_STATE_RECEIVED object:nil];
}

- (void)removeNotificationObserver
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NOTIF_ESSMQTT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NOTIF_DEVICE_STATES_RECEIVED object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NOTIF_DEVICE_ON_OFF_STATE_RECEIVED object:nil];
}
```

I am using `NSNotification` to refresh states of my buttons and images within this `UITableViewCell`.

The problem I am facing is, every time an NSNotication is received, the `awakeFromNib` is called. This will cause the states of my buttons and images to refresh back to its initial states. **The strange thing is, I never saw `removeFromSuperview` getting called before that.**

So my questions are:

1. Why is `awakeFromNib` getting called when `NSNotification` is received?
2. I am just wondering, is adding observer under `awakeFromNib` the correct thing to do when you want your `UITableViewCells` to observe `NSNotifications`? (Well, I've been doing this all the time.)

Comment: where you have added observer for notification?

Comment: @MangeshMurhe Hi, I edited my post, kindly check.

Comment: When you want to remove observer?

Comment: @MangeshMurhe Uhm, maybe my question is a bit confusing. I edited my first question. I just want to know why awakeFromNib is called when an NSNotification is received.

Comment: awakeFromNib is mostly called on unarchiving object from xib.In your case i think it is called on cell reload and not on notification received.Are yourefreshing cell on some event?

Comment: @MangeshMurhe I see, I'll have a good check at my code. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, where you have initiated UITableViewCell

Comment: @MangeshMurhe Hey, thanks for the reminder. After looking at my code closely, I noticed that I am refreshing my table after receiving a notification. That solved my problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: @finalstatic welcome.Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Because your cell was refreshed content but did not be remove from superview

You had to call removeNotificationObserver when content of cell was refreshed successfully.

I suggest you using protocol instead of notification.

Hope help.